# Following relationships "backward" and using QuerySet

Tags: django

[This is the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for following relationships in django

```
>>> b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
>>> b.entry_set.all() # Returns all Entry objects related to Blog.
```

I want to list all Blog objects and entries in a list:

```
  Blog1
   <ul>
    <li>Entry1 for Blog1</li>
    <li>Entry2 for Blog1</li>
   </ul>
  Blog2
   <ul>
    <li>Entry1 for Blog2</li>
    <li>Entry2 for Blog2</li>
   </ul>
```

Is there any way for do this? something like `b = Blog.objects.all()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to iterate over `Blog.objects.all()` and access each `.entry_set.all()` in turn.

Comment: I have tried this before but I have the error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'entry_set'. I dont use related_name in foreignkey filed

Comment: Again, you need to **iterate over it**.

Comment: Would you please give any example link or document? There is only this in documentation:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/  . Thanks

Comment: `for i in someiterable:` `dosomethingwith(i)`

Comment: `for b in Blog.objects.all():
  for e in b.entry_set.all():
    print e`